# Angular 2, Spring Security: Cross origin POST won't send cookiens

Tags: http, angular, cookies, spring-security

Hi I have the following app:

- **Frontend** is in Angular 2 running on **localhost:4200**
- **Backened** is in Spring running on **localhost:8080**

I am using **Spring Security**. On the server site I have **CORSFilter**:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Here is the client site:

```
private static headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
private static postOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: SecureHttpService.headers });
private static getOptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({});


constructor(private http: Http) {
     SecureHttpService.postOptions.withCredentials = true;
     SecureHttpService.getOptions.withCredentials = true;
}

public get(url: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(url, SecureHttpService.getOptions);
}

public post(url: string, data: any): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post(url, data, SecureHttpService.postOptions);
}
```

As you can see I set **withCredentials = true;**

*Here is my problem:*

- on **HTTP GET** the **SESSIONID** is send.

[image]

- on **HTTP POST** the **SESSIONID** in **NOT send**.  **Why???**

[image]
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

Based of reading this great [article](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/), the preflighted requests work like that:

*"The browser first executes an OPTIONS request with the same URL as the target request to check that it has the rights to execute the request. This OPTIONS request returns headers that identify what is possible to do for the URL. If rights match, the browser executes the request."*

[image]

So **I added the filter** to Spring that will pass all **OPTIONS** requests.

```
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String httpmethod = request.getMethod();

    if(httpmethod.equals("OPTIONS")) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

*!Please note that I am using this solution only for development.*